# Throws exception and breaks the flow but the data is available in the sequence

Tags: c#, linq

The below code throws `sequence does not contain the matching element`.

```
var inavailableous = userOuIds.Any(n => ("," + item.AvailableOUs + ",").Contains(n));
```

Where `userOuIds` is `List<string>` has value as `,1,` and the `item.AvailableOUs` is `string` has values `1,2,3,4,5,6`.

Please help me what is going wrong with the code?

Comment: Sorry its really hard to read your mind, and your code we cant see, what are the types involved here like `item.AvailableOUs`, `userOuIds` and `n`

Comment: assuming both userOuIds and AvailableOUs are both strings this works just fine for me.

Comment: @MichaelRandall updated my question. Sorry I missed that.

Comment: @BijayYadav - Your question doesn't make sense. Please write it so that all of the data is valid C# code.

Comment: are you sure you don't want it the other way around?

Comment: Is there a call stack?

Comment: @qxg - What do you mean?

Comment: Figured out the issue resolution posted as an answer. His comment looks as below.

Can you check if the values of userOuIds and item.AvailableOUs is in proper format? For example.

`userOuIds` is `, 1,` or `,1 ,` instead of `,1,`.
`item.AvailableOUs` is `1,2,3,4,5,6`.